# trouble with importing scikit-image new version - 14 in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, scikit-image

H, I have tried importing scikit-images from pycharm interpreter. I t can only show me the available version upto 0.13.1 but i want to install scikit-image 0.14.

I have installed the newest version through terminal but pycharm dosenot seems to acknowledge this and it;s just reading from its own libraries where it certainly cannot find 0.14.

I wan to use 0.14 because 0.13.1 gives me error with skimage.feature.canny-->  http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html

I am using python 2.7 and python 3.5.   I am switching between 2.7 and 3.5. I have tried installing for both of them but no luck. The reason i found is that pycharm is looking for packages in the following directory: pypi.python.org/simple and the latest package availabe there is 0.13.1. It dose not matter whatever version i installed via terminal (of skimage / scikit-image). It keep looking for the version in the pycharm dir.

Comment: 0.14 is not yet released

Comment: yea??????  but why i am not able to use cv2.canny() function.???

and yes it's released:   http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html

Comment: I'm one of the project maintainers, and I'm saying you that 0.14 is currently in the development phase. So, "yea". `cv2.canny` has nothing to do with `scikit-image`.

Comment: yeap. Mybad. I found it. I was following the tutorial on internet and it has this convention which led me to this problem. Mny Thanks Mate:)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `preferences` -> `project` and check which installation of Python you have set for the project interpreter. You need to either change the interpreter to be the version of Python where you upgraded scikit-image, or upgrade scikit-image for that version of Python.